# Run a powershell script from TFSBuild.Proj file

Tags: powershell, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have added a code piece in my MS build file to run a powershell script. But while building it gives me a error **error MSB4067: The element "Exec" beneath element "Project" is unrecognized.**

Below is the code:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PowerShellExe Condition=" '$(PowerShellExe)'=='' ">
    %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
  </PowerShellExe>
  <ScriptLocation Condition=" '$(ScriptLocation)'=='' ">
    D:\Synopsis\SynopsysDetect.ps1
  </ScriptLocation>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Exec Command="%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command ^&quot;^&amp; {^&amp;&apos;D:\Synopsis\SynopsysDetect.ps1&apos;} ^&quot;" />
```

Not sure if the issue is with code or have I placed the code piece at the wrong place. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think this must be inside a target.

Comment: What version of TFS is this for? `tfsbuild.proj` files were deprecated in TFS 2010, so about **ten years ago**. If you're still on TFS 2008, you are way, way overdue for an upgrade as that version of TFS, the version of SQL server it runs on, and the OS it runs on are all long past the point of being supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the above piece of code completely into the "Target" tag fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**MSB4067  is "UnrecognizedChildElement"**. It means that the element containing this line doesn't "know" the exec command. Since the tag `</PropertyGroup>` is above your line, I have no idea how your structure look like. Please share more of the file blurring confidential parts.

Also see that TFS has a "Run powershell step" that you can use.